# Запомнить авторизованного пользователя webview flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

Как можно реализовать запоминание авторизованного пользователя после закрытия приложения webview flutter?
Например есть сайт, который мы запускаем через webview flutter и на сайте есть авторизация. После авторизации и выхода из приложения нужно снова проходить авторизацию. Как можно реализовать запоминание авторизованного пользователя? Подскажите пожалуйста и если можно с объяснениями как это можно сделать.

Comment: Каким образом реализована авторизация на сайте?

Comment: Авторизация на фреймворке laravel

Comment: Есть два способа: 1) сохранять и восстанавливать cookie. 2) получать и сохранить auth header и использовать его когда запускается web view.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) для сохранения любой информации.
Вот ссылка на документацию [Документация](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Если нужен пример кода, то напишу его немного позже.

Comment: @Nikolay Да, не забудте написать короткий пример. Отвеы содержащие только ссылку, обычно удаляются.